# Adding external jars in netbeans for rest service in glassfish

Tags: rest, netbeans, glassfish, jax-rs

I'm trying to create a simple `REST` Service using the `Web App` project type in `Netbeans 8.1`, with `JDK 1.8` and to be deployed in `Glassfish Server 4.1.1`.
I need to use external libraries to provide the service functionality, i.e. tika and lucene.

My problem is that If I add any jar (Right-click -> Add jar/folder: tika-app-1.12.jar) in the Libraries of my Nb project I get:

- An error when deploying:

> Grave:   Class [ javax/cache/configuration/Configuration ] not found.
>   Error while loading [ class
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.cache.CacheControlFeature ]

- An error when invoking:

> Advertencia:   StandardWrapperValve[BusquedaApplication]:
>   Servlet.service() for servlet BusquedaApplication threw exception
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation.JAXRSBeanValidationInInterceptor.filter(JAXRSBeanValidationInInterceptor.java:64)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFilteringStage.apply(ContainerFilteringStage.java:132)
>   ...

I have tried adding the jar file in `glassfish/lib`, `glassfish/domains/<mydomain>/lib` and `glassfish/domains/<mydomain>/lib/ext` but the error persists.
Note that these errors show up as soon as I add the jar in the Nb libraries folder, whether I reference them in my code or not.

If I remove the jars the service gets deployed without error and I can also invoke it correctly and get the appropiate response.

Any insight in the correct way to deal with these external libraries is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I have figured it out.

To be able to use the external libraries:

- Don't package them in the `war` file. In Nb: go to `Project Properties -> Libraries -> Compile-time libraries`. Then uncheck the Package box for all the listed libraries.
- Copy all the `.jar` libraries to the `<domains-folder>/<your-domain-name>/lib`. Be aware that your domain folder may not be in the installation directory of Glassfish. You can check the Server properties in Nb (Go to `Services tab -> right-click Glassfish server -> Properties -> Common  -> Domains Folder`)
- Use delegation inversion model in the Servlet. To do this, set `delegate="false"` in the `class-loader` element of the `glassfish-web.xml` file.

This worked for me. I hope I can help anyone else in a similar situation.